# How to insert New Lines when Writing to a Text File in Java

Tags: java

I would like to create a simple program (in Java) which edits text files - particularly one which performs inserting arbitrary pieces of text at random positions in a text file.

**Old Text file:**

```
Noodles
Cereal
Tomato
Carrot
Fish
Meat
```

**Output:**

```
Please insert new record:
1
Cornflake

Please insert new record:
```

**New Text File:**

```
Noodles
Cereal
Tomato
Carrot
Fish
Meat
Cornflake
```

I check on my text file and it insert into my text file but when I run program again, for example, I want to insert Ice-Cream then it should added after Cornflake but instead it replace Cornflake with Ice-Cream. But how can I resolve this problem?

**Java:**

```
String INPUT_PROMPT ="Please insert new record:";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
            line = reader.readLine();

while(!line.equals("x"))
{ 
          switch(line)
          {       
              case "1":
              line = reader.readLine();  

                    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(inFile);
                    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(bw);

                    for(int k=0; k< prdct.size(); k++)
                    {
                        pw.println(prdct.get(k).toString());
                    }
                    pw.write(line);
                    pw.write("\n");
                    pw.close();    
                    break;
          }  
            System.out.println(INPUT_PROMPT);
            line = reader.readLine();  


}
```

Comment: Question re-asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014744/append-a-new-line-of-text-to-an-existing-text-file-using-java). Ramzi -- please don't do this!

Answer (score 2):

This question is probably a duplicate of many others, but you need to open the `FileWriter` in append mode, which is done by passing `true` as the second parameter in the constructor:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(inFile, true);
```

From the [Javadoc for FileWriter(File file, boolean append)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)):

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.